# Python 3 regex to split list of items?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm reading in some data in the form a list of items, space separated. Each item has a name, which may be one or more words, and a quantity which can either be a single integer or a fraction of integers.

Ex.

```
'12 Spruce Log 4/5 Water 3 Orange 3/18 Oak Plank'
```

I want this split into the following list:

```
['12 Spruce Log', '4/5 Water', '3 Orange', '3/18 Oak Plank']
```

Here is my Python regex:

```
import re
re.findall(r'\d+(/\d+)?\D+', "12 Spruce Log 4/5 Water 3 Orange 3/18 Oak Plank")
```

This produces the following result, which is obviously not right:

```
['', '/5', '', '/18']
```

What is the proper regex here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = '12 Spruce Log 4/5 Water 3 Orange 3/18 Oak Plank'
new_s = re.split('(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s(?=\d)', s)
```

Output:

```
['12 Spruce Log', '4/5 Water', '3 Orange', '3/18 Oak Plank']
```

Or, just using `re.findall`:

```
new_list = [i[:-1] if i.endswith(' ') else i for i in re.findall('[\d\/]+\s[a-zA-Z\s]+(?=\d)|[\d\/]+\s[a-zA-Z\s]+(?=$)', s)]
```

Output:

```
['12 Spruce Log', '4/5 Water', '3 Orange', '3/18 Oak Plank']
```

Comment: use raw string for regex, or you're gonna fail in Python 3.7

Comment: Why `(?<=[a-zA-Z])`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann `(?<=[a-zA-Z])` is merely one way of ensuring that the regex always splits after the end of an item, and before the start of the item quantity.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @mario_sunny glad to help!

Comment: @Ajax1234 Can you show an example where that helps?

Answer (score 0):

So here is what i came up with:

```
/(?:\d+\/\d+|\d+)\s(?:[[:word:]]+\s*){1,2}(?=\d|$)/g
```

[demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/InCXT1/1)